# Fitting to an implicit function

Tags: equation-solving, fitting, implicit

I am trying to fit a data

```
data = {{290, 0.112089478}, {240, 0.072525194}, {220, 0.063863975}, {200,0.075709626}, {170,0.076462613}, {150, 0.070010656}, {130, 0.065390206}, {120, 0.064750065}, {100, 0.134944754}, {91, 0.257195474}, {60, 0.364253}, {40, 0.698189999}, {30, 1.084079999},{20, 1.2336},{14,1.295300001},{4.2, 1.23443379}};
```

to the this function :

```
a x ((4 Γ^2 + y^2)/y^6)
```

and

```
y=
```

is also an implicit function of x as

```
y == Sqrt[1 + β/y (1/(Exp[y/x] - 1) + 1/2 - y/2)]
```

This is what I already have :

```
fitfunc[b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, \[Beta]_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
x (10 b + (c/100000) (y^2 + 2 y))/(y^2 + 2 y)^3 /. 
FindRoot[
y == Sqrt[1 + \[Beta]/y (1/(Exp[y/x] - 1) + 1/2 - y/2)], {y, 1}];
sol = NonlinearModelFit[
data, {fitfunc[b, c, \[Beta], x], {b > 0, 
 c > 0, \[Beta] > 0}}, {{b, 8}, {c, 1.3}, {\[Beta], 15}}, x];
sol["BestFitParameters"]
(*{b\[Rule]0.006022963413091671`,c\[Rule]2.2302423416894093`,\[Beta]\
\[Rule]20`}*)

(*Original parameters*)

 Solve[{a 4 \[CapitalGamma]^2 == 10 b, a == c/100000} /. 
sol["BestFitParameters"], {a, \[CapitalGamma]}][[2]]
(*{a\[Rule]1.89546\[Times]10^-7`,\[CapitalGamma]\[Rule]512.\
7858713433279`}*)

Show[ListPlot[data], 
Plot[fitfunc[b, c, \[Beta], x] /. sol["BestFitParameters"], {x, 4, 
300}]]
```

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: When plotting add `PlotRange -> {Automatic, All}` in order to see the curve over the entire range. I think you have the procedure down correctly. The basic problem is that your model simply doesn't fit the data.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question?  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/155769/fitting-to-a-complicated-implicit-function

Comment: My data fits the model but I couldn't fit it.  It is the same question but since I couldn't find the answer for it I thought to repost it.

Comment: 1) The data points in your last plot don't match the `data` list you provide. 2) Trying `Manipulate[
 Show[ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[fitfunc[b, c, \[Beta], x], {x, 4, 300}, PlotRange -> All]],
 {b, 0, 50}, {c, 0, 50}, {\[Beta], 0, 50}]`, I couldn't find anything that was any better than what _Mathematica_ found, possibly due to the fact that **`c` seemed to have no discernible effect whatsoever**. I would really make sure that your model is correct, because it looks like something has got lost somewhere.